# TranslateZ Percentages CSS 3D Transforms

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I try to set percentages in translateZ like this:

```
transform:translateZ(-100%);
```

it doesn't work. It also doesn't work with viewport relative `vh` or `vw`. Is there some way to do this? I understand that I can simply set it with JavaScript, but I have many of these elements in a certain class, including ones that are added later dynamically with JavaScript. It would be much more convenient to do something in CSS. I saw something which seemed like a duplicate, but I would like a way that doesn't have to have multiple elements to fix it. Apart from appending to the `<style>` element, that is

Comment: What results do you expect ? 100% of what ?

Answer (score 14):

Well, reading the w3c specification for translateZ, it's not clear that anybody has think about what should do a percentage value there ..(or at least, it's not clear for me what should be the implementation).

What has been decided in the standard, however, is that translateX(100%) will be relative to width.

So, a way to get what you want would be to rotate until the x axis is in the z axis, do a x translation, and restore the rotation:

CSS

```
transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateX(100%) rotateY(90deg);
```

In this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/LKZZB/) you can see that the test element, that has that transform applied, gets to the same position that the ref element , that has a translateZ(100px) applied (since the element width is 100px)

Comment: @ZachSaucier Nice to see you again ! I see that you have got to 10k. Congratulations !!!!

Comment: Rework it so you don't need to fix the problem. I like it!